# Do non-microphone standard stereo headphones work with PS Vita?

Tags: ps-vita

Do stereo headphones without microphones work with the PS Vita?

Comment: Yes they will..

Comment: I've been using an Apple iPod headphone on my Vita for years. It works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Anything that is a standard 3.5mm jack headphone will work on the PS Vita; it's a standard output and will work with mono/stereo headphones/speakers that use that port.

Comment: Moron question, but I assume "standard 3.5mm jack" extends to the same kind of headphones you might have used on Walkman players long ago?

Comment: @garrettendi yeah, the little tiny round ports with a single hole, as opposed to micro/mini/USB ports or XLR ports

Comment: Thanks Ben, I know that was a moron question to ask but I wanted to be sure I wouldn't damage my Vita